# Why does If statement throw an undefined error when I am checking if its undefined?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Why does my else if statement cause the parser to throw an undefined error? I know that it is undefined which is why I am checking, I want it to hit the else block in this case, because this function is used in mutiple places the data that is being passed in is not always the same. So I am trying to check which type of data is being passed in.

```
if(icon){
    dv.find(".mobCol>.image").html(generateIcon(icon));
}
else if(location[0].properties !== undefined){
    dv.find(".mobCol>.image").html(generateIcon(location[0].properties.image));
    data = location[0];
}
else{
    dv.find(".mobCol>.image").html(generateIcon(location.features[0].properties.image));
    data = location.features[0];
}
```

Comment: `!=` instead of `!==`

Comment: @John That won't solve any parser errors.

Comment: Because you're checking at least one level past where the `undefined` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because location[0] is undefined. It's a bit odd, but your check should be:

```
if( location[0] && location[0].properties){ /* .. */}
```

I've omitted the `===undefined`, thats not needed. It tests if it is something is [thruthy or falsey](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)
This is a common way to check variables in JS.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you!

Comment: "If something is set, it'll return true" is false though. If location[0] is null, false, 0, NaN or empty string it will also return false.

Comment: Rephrazed it with a link :)